# How to redirect different different controllers action after sing_in from devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new in ROR and I am using Rails 5 version I have successfully created sign_in functionality from devise.

I am using devise for sign_in, sign_up etc.

I have created three roles: `super_admin`, `manager` and `moderator`.

super_admin have all manage permission but others don't.

```
get 'manager/dashboard', :as => 'manager_dashboard'
get 'moderator/dashboard', :as => 'moderator_dashboard'
get 'users/dashboard', :as => 'users_dashboard'
root "home#index"
devise_for :users
```

I want after sign_in redirect to different controller actions using devise.

- super_admin after sign_in redirect users#dashboard.
- manager after sign_in redirect manager#dashboard.
- moderator after sign_in redirect moderator#dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `after_sign_in_path`.

In your `ApplicationController`, define a method `after_sign_path_for(resource)`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.super_admin?
    users_dashboard_path
  elsif resource.manager?
    manager_dashboard_path
  else
    moderator_dashboard_path
  end
end
```